# Compare two tables and give the rows that are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. There are two columns common in the tables. Table one is the parent table and table 2 is a subset of the primary table. I want to get the rows which they do not have in common.

Ex:

- table 1: a, b, c, d
- table 2: c

Expected result: a,b,d

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What if table 2 also has value 'e', and another value 'c'?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you what you want.

```
SELECT t1.val
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.val != t2.val
```

Output:

```
val
a
b
d
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97610/2/0

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, you don't need any extra ordinary query

```
SELECT tab1.val
FROM table1 tab1, table2 Tab2
WHERE tab1.FieldName <> tab2.FieldName
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DBMS support MINUS statement you can use:

```
SELECT COL1
FROM TABLE1
MINUS
SELECT COL1
FROM TABLE2
```

Note that minus is positional. You won't get the same result switching the two SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select    X.ID   
From    Table1    X    
Right    Join    Table2    Y    ON    (X.ID =  Y.ID) 
Where     Y.ID   IS     NULL
```

There are two tables Table1 and Table2   having reference column  as  ID .   Above query  shows output where   Unmatched IDs in   table 1 are  showed.

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it clearer for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....
Referring c as the common column...

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE c NOT IN
(SELECT c FROM Table2);
```